# Macos x Shortcuts of a Application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I need to read all Shortcuts of the frontmost Application in MAC OS. Is there a API or Class in Cocoa,Objective-c who provides this?

Comment: What do you mean by shortcuts? Can you explain what you're trying to do in more detail?

Comment: No problem. I give you an example. Let us say the Application Safari is active. What i trying to do is to read all Shortcuts/Hotkeys which registered for this app. Maybe there is a file or a Method which i can read this?

Comment: Take a look at the [Accessibility framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Accessibility/cocoaAXIntro/cocoaAXintro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000118i). It should provide you with a way to access the menus of running applications, which will likely allow you to read the items' assigned keys.

Comment: I done this. But i didn't find a function or the correct way to do this. Do you know where i can find a example code? I found the UIElementInspector but theres nothing in this direction implemented.

Comment: Even if you read all the menu items, that'll only give you some of the app's keyboard shortcuts. To use the Safari example, there are some shortcuts, such as `⇧⌘]` to move to the next tab, that don't show up in the menus. Unfortunately I think the answer to your question is no -- there are too many ways for an app to respond to hotkeys, and many don't involve registering anywhere that an API would be able to see.

Comment: @SeanD. - How about this app Cheatsheet (http://mediaatelier.com/CheatSheet/) which shows a list of all the keyboard shortcuts? I tried it in some IDEs as well (Sublime text 2) and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @ShiVik: That appears to use the technique Itai pointed to, getting everything in the menus. With Safari, to pick one example, it doesn't catch `⇧⌘[` and `⇧⌘]` for switching between tabs. But if all Togo needs is a listing of menu items, the Accessibility framework should work for that much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Accessibility API is what you need. Unfortunately, it is rather convoluted, and it would be good to read through the UIElementInspector [source code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/UIElementInspector/Introduction/Intro.html) to see how it's used, as well as the sections relevant to assistive applications in the [Accessibility Programming Guidelines for Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Accessibility/cocoaAXIntro/cocoaAXintro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000118-SW1).

What you want would take a good bit of code so I will just outline the steps.

1. Use `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications]` to get a list of applications and get the application whose `active` property is `YES`.
2. Get the PID of that application using the `NSRunningApplication`'s `processIdentifier` property.
3. Now we get to Accessibility, accessed through the [Application Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Accessibility/Reference/AccessibilityLowlevel/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001097) API
4. Create an AXUIElement representing the active Application using [`AXUIElementCreateApplication`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accessibility/Reference/AccessibilityLowlevel/AXUIElement_h/CompositePage.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AXUIElementCreateApplication), which takes `pid` as the argument.
5. Now you have an `AXUIElement` with the `Application` role, or `AXApplication` pseudo-class. You'll want to proceed down the hierarch of elements `AXApplication` -> `AXMenuBar` -> `AXMenuBarItem` -> `AXMenuItem`. Note that `AXMenuItems` can have other `AXMenuItems` nested under them.
6. To traverse the hierarchy, use [`AXUIElementCopyAttributeValues`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accessibility/Reference/AccessibilityLowlevel/AXUIElement_h/CompositePage.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AXUIElementCopyAttributeValues) to get the values of [`kAXChildrenAttribute`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accessibility/Reference/AccessibilityCarbonRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/kAXChildrenAttribute). This will return an array of children `AXUIElements`.
7. Finally, when you get to `AXMenuItem` elements, examine their Menu Item Cmd Char, Glyph, Modifiers, and Virtual Key attributes for the actual shortcuts. The constants for the attribute names, like `kAXMenuItemCmdCharAttribute`, are listed [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/Accessibility_RoleAttribute_Ref/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007870-Attributes-AXMenuItemCmdChar).

Comment: Thanks woody. I done this already in the way you described. The App is released in the first version have a look at it: https://github.com/Togo/eve

Comment: @Togo Wow, I'm really late to the game then. Glad you got it working! Though it would be a good idea to post your own answer and accept it for a question that went unanswered like this, for the sake of the community :)

Answer (score 0):

Not trying to compete @woody :)

But I found this, and it might help too:

[UI Browser](http://pfiddlesoft.com/uibrowser/index.html)